# How does "lack of character" compare with simply being bad or evil?

Tags: meaning

My sense of the former term is someone might fail to respond vigorously to evil without initiating it or taking pleasure in it. But I have not seen clear definitions of "character" or lack thereof. Perhaps lack of character is more akin to being physically weak/infirm?

Comment: Have you tried looking up "character" in a dictionary?

Comment: A lazy or obnoxious person might be considered to have poor character, but they're not evil.

Answer (score 0):

[Lack of character](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/lacking_in_character.html#:%7E:text=lacking%20in%20character%3F-,Adjective,colorlessUS) is giving in to specific situations. Not standing up to defend your beliefs, values, or morals. [Bad/evil](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evil#:%7E:text=%3A%20morally%20reprehensible%20%3A%20sinful%2C%20wicked,a%20person%20of%20evil%20reputation) refers to a person who has the direct conscious intent to cause moral, physical, or emotional damage to others.